# How to connect via FTP to an android studio device?

Tags: android

Is it possible to connect your phone to debug applications through the FTP server? there is no cable at hand and there is no way to buy.

Comment: How is FTP related to debugging something? You need to add a lot more details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several Android Studio plugins that purport to allow debugging via WiFi. Just search for 'WiFi' under `File/Settings/Plugins`. Unfortunately, I think the initial setup of the more popular ones requires a USB connection. So if you could borrow a cable for a few minutes...